# How can i display a certain attribute in a certain table without displaying all for a current user RAILS 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `student` and `school` database tied to my rails project I have these attributes for **student table**:

```
[id,fname,lname,created_at,updated_at,school_id,user_id]
```

and my **school table** has these attributes

```
[id,name,address,franchise_id,created_at,updated_at]
```

so far I am trying to display the school `name` for each student that a current user may have. but when I run it, it will show all the schools for all the students of that user on each iteration of the loop. here is my index action method where the magic is supposed to happen.

```
  @child = Student.where(user_id:current_user.id).pluck(:school_id)
  @schoolname = School.where(id:@child).pluck(:name)
```

and my index page in my view:

```
 <div class="container">
 <h1><font color="white"><b>My students</font></b></h1>

 <table class="table table-striped">
 <thead>
  <tr>
  <th><font color="white"><b>Id</font></b></th>
  <th><font color="white"><b>Fname</font></b></th>
  <th><font color="white"><b>Lname</font></b></th>
  <th><font color="white"><b>School</font></b></th>
  <th><font color="white"><b>manage</font></b></th>
  <th colspan="3"></th>
   </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
   <% @students.each do |student| %>
      <tr>
        <td><font color="white"><b><%= student.id %></font></b></td>
       <td><font color="white"><b><%= student.fname %></font></b></td>
       <td><font color="white"><b><%= student.lname %></font></b></td>
       <td><font color="white"><b><%= @schoolname %></font></b></td>
       <td><%= link_to 'Show', student %>
       <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_student_path(student) %>
       <%= link_to 'Destroy', student, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 
       'Are you sure?' } %></td>
       </tr>
        <% end %>
        </tbody>
       </table>

       <br>

       <b><%= link_to 'Add Student', add_students_path(@student),
       {:style=>'color:#FFFFFF;'} %></b><br/>

       <b> <%= link_to 'New Student', new_student_path, 
        {:style=>'color:#FFFFFF;'} %></b>
          </div>
```

my model is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of @schoolname in your loop in view, write
`student.school.name`
If your one-to-many relationship works, this should work.

Comment: yep that did it. didnt know u could call it like that, lol after 4 hours of trying to get that.hahahah thats programming for you...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't the ability to comment but I wanted to ask where you assign `@students`? You use it in your view but I don't see it in your controller's index method. Also `@student` should be `student` in the `link_to` methods at the end.